# Get ID via class name

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this element:

```
<div class="item item-id-123"></div>
```

I want to put the ID in a variable via the class name `item-id-123`.

So I target the element via `.item`:

```
$( document ).on( 'click', '.item', function() {
    // get the ID via class name
});
```

Maybe I can use `.match()` to get the class name, and then strip `item-id-` from it so we have `123` left...? What's the appropriate approach here?

Comment: Why just do this? `<div class="item" id="item-id-123"></div>`.

Comment: @RadonirinaMaminiaina I can't alter the HTML.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're not sure about the position of your `class` in the attribute, you can use the RegEx [`item-id-(\d+)`](https://regex101.com/r/qQP90D/1/)

```js
$(document).on('click', '.item', function() {
  console.log(/item-id-(\d+)/.exec($(this).attr('class'))[1]);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="item item-id-123">Click me</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that sample `item item-id-123`, you can split the class names and get the number part using a regex.

This approach breaks the loop when a match is found.

```js
$(document).on('click', '.item', function() {
  var names = $(this).attr('class').split(/\s+/);
  var id;
  for (var name of names) {
    var aux;
    if ((aux = name.replace(/[^\d]+/, '').trim()) !== '') {
      id = aux;
      break;
    }
  }
  console.log(id);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="item item-id-123">Click me!</div>
```

Or, even simpler, get the captured group related to `id-number`:

```js
$(document).on('click', '.item', function() {
  var id = $(this).attr('class').match(/id-(\d+)/).pop();
  console.log(id);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="item item-id-123 another-class-567">Click me!</div>
```

Comment: What if the other classes contain numbers?

Comment: @Zenoo I've stated: *This approach breaks the loop when a match is found.*

Answer (score 2):

This is alternative to @Zenoo's answer, just without the regex.

```js
$(document).on('click', '.item', function() {
  console.log($(this).attr('class').split("item-id-")[1].split(" ")[0]);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="item something here item-id-123 hHmmMM hey">Click me</div>
```

Comment: What if there are some other classes after?

Comment: @Zenoo looks like a valid point, actually. Then, I'll see if I can provide a solution different than yours.

Comment: Going with @Zenoo 's solution, but thank you for the alternative.

Answer (score 1):

If your structure is always:

```
<div class="item item-id-123"></div>
```

Then you can try this if you won't regex:

```js
$( '.item' ).on( 'click', function() {
   // get the ID via class name
   var id = $(this).attr('class').split('item-id-')[1];
   $('#result').text(id)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="item item-id-123">click me</span>
<div id="result"></div>
```

Answer (score -2):

ID with numbers as in your example

```js
$( document ).on( 'click', '.item', function() {
    console.log($(this).attr("class").match(/\d+/)[0]);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="item item-id-123">click</div>
```